# Is a convert required to immediately choose a sect, e.g. Sunni or Shia?

Tags: conversion, sects

If a non-Muslim wants to convert to Islam does he need to choose between Shia or Sunni point of view at the time of conversion? Or is it just a matter of belief and he doesn't need to choose between that?

Comment: This question should be closed immediately. There is no doubt that there will be conflict in the comments on which sect is the right sect.

Comment: No, he/she just converts, you don't need to mention anything about what sect/madhab you want to follow (even if  you dont know). That would just make everything hard and scare away converts!

Comment: I'm non-denominational. (:

Comment: @RebeccaJ.Stones Your personal choices aren't doctrinally instructive, I don't think that'll help people passing through here figure out what Islam has to say about the question.

Comment: I don't understand how people can be non-denominational. @RebeccaJ.Stones  You even said that you learnt the 'Hanafi' way to pray.

Comment: Non-denominational means you follow whatever feels right to you from Quran. Not take one madhab as the whole and only way, learn from every scholar and every situation. Why my answer was deleted?

Comment: @lsmasou i would speculate it got deleted because it was accepted while it didn't answer the question about if a convert is required to choose a sect or not instead your answer only brought up the controversial idea that one shouldn't follow a sect at all, which really isn't an answer. Please read our "how to answer" article in the help section.

Comment: @Armaan Hanafi way is not termed as denomination it is a Madhab in Fiqh.

Comment: It is a madhab of Sunni denomination!

Comment: Sorry I should not ask this question. Anyone can delete my question....

Answer (score 5):

A non-Muslim who elects to convert to Islam, at the time of conversion, does need not to select between different sects, different schools of jurisprudence, or otherwise. The requirement to become a Muslim is to say *Al-Shahadatayn* (testimony of faith) in private or in public, which marks a person as entering the fold of Islam. It is preferred to perform *ghusl* (wash) then to pray two rak'as after the testimony of faith.

To continue being a Muslim afterwards, one has to uphold the five pillars of Islam:

1. *Al-Shahaadatayn* (testimony of faith)
2. *Salah* (prayers)
3. *Zakaah* (financial dues)
4. *Sawm Ramadan* (fasting the month of Ramadan)
5. *Hajj* (pilgrimage)

There are numerous verses that enumerate the pillars. Here is a hadith that is quite well known:

> #### بُنِيَ الإِسْلاَمُ عَلَى خَمْسٍ شَهَادَةِ أَنْ لاَ إِلَهَ إِلاَّ اللَّهُ وَأَنَّ مُحَمَّدًا رَسُولُ اللَّهِ، وَإِقَامِ الصَّلاَةِ، وَإِيتَاءِ الزَّكَاةِ، وَالْحَجِّ، وَصَوْمِ رَمَضَانَ
>
> Islam is based on [the following] five [principles]: To testify that none has the right to be worshiped but Allah and Muhammad is Allah's Messenger (ﷺ), to offer the [compulsory congregational] prayers dutifully and perfectly, to pay Zakat [i.e. obligatory charity], to perform Hajj [i.e. Pilgrimage to Mecca], and to observe fast during the month of Ramadan.
>
> <sub>— [Sahih Al-Bukhari 2/1](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/2/1/)</sub>